# Where can I open Adobe Illustrator files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I ordered a logo and I received AI file. I do not own Adobe Illustrator and it makes no sense for me to buy it as I am not a designer.

I can export it using [online services](https://cloudconvert.com/ai-to-png) which suites most of my needs. But I would like to do trivial modifications like scaling, cropping etc. Is there any free (budget) software where I can do such tasks with AI file?

I have already found this similar question: [How to edit/export ai file without Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/57947/64290)

Comment: You should ask your designer for a PDF or other output that you require. Interesting that they gave you the source since often times designers will not do so unless paid extra.

Comment: Did you grab the free trial of Illustrator already? They'll give you a full 30 days for free, if you only have a few modifications to make it might be enough? http://www.adobe.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can open AI files in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), an open-source vector graphics editor for free on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

> **What formats can Inkscape import/export?**
>
> Inkscape natively supports opening or importing SVG, SVGZ (gzipped SVG), PDF and Adobe
>   Illustrator (.ai) formats. And, as of version 0.91, Inkscape can
>   import CDR (CorelDraw) and VSD (Visio) natively.

[Frequently Asked Questions — for Inkscape Users](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/)

Alternatively, you could always download a free trial of Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Comment: If you have "Adobe Acrobat" you can open .ai easily with it and you can do some modification like scaling moving.

Comment: @hsawires Can this be done with the free version of Adobe Acrobat, ie. Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Comment: If you're downloading assets from Adobe Stock and trying to open in Inkscape, try renaming the extension to EPS. Only way I got it to work on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this: http://www.coreldraw.com/en/pages/ai-file/ it worked in my case

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape wasn’t able to open the graphics I wanted, so I tried doing as [@pspahn mentioned](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69645/where-can-i-open-adobe-illustrator-files#comment206051_69647) in a comment on the accepted answer: I renamed the `.ai` file to `.eps`, and then Inkscape imported it perfectly. I’m not sure if this will work with all `.ai` files, but thus far it has worked with all the ones I needed to import.

Answer (score -1):

Try finishing the file in Adobe Illustrator. Then convert it from [AI to PNG](https://www.converter365.com/vector-converter/ai/ai-to-png)
That might work...